# Distinguishing between two array indices?

Tags: c, arrays, primes

I'm having trouble with arrays. I copied this code from a book:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

int main (void)
{
    int     p, i, primes[50], primeIndex = 2;
    bool    isPrime;

    primes[0] = 2;
    primes[1] = 3;

    for (p = 5; p <= 50; p = p + 2) {
        isPrime = true;

        for (i = 1; isPrime && p / primes[i] >= primes[i]; ++i)
            if (p % primes[i] == 0)
                isPrime = false;

        if (isPrime == true) {
            primes[primeIndex] = p;
            ++primeIndex;
        }
    }

    for (i = 0; i < primeIndex; ++i)
        printf ("%i ", primes[i]);

    printf ("\n");

    return 0;
}
```

In particular, I'm having trouble understanding the difference between the `primeIndex` and the `i` variables. The `primeIndex` refers to the array number and `i` refers to the number placed into the array. Right?

Comment: Anyone knows the name of this algorithm?

Comment: Note that when you set `isPrime = false;`, you could also sensibly add a `break;` (and braces `{ ... }`) to terminate the loop early.

Comment: Even worse: the whole boolean (loop invariant+1/2) `isPrime` could be eliminated by a goto, and the add-to-array could be condensed to `primes[primeIndex++] = p;` BTW the `p <= 50` test should be `primeIndex < 50`

Comment: @bacchus It's trial division. Just using the found primes to avoid pointless divisions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`primeIndex` is the place where the next found prime is written in the `prime` array, and also the number of primes known so far. `i` is the index of the prime used for trial division. For each candidate, `i` loops from 1 (we don't need to try out `primes[0] = 2` because only odd numbers are checked) to the index of the first prime larger than the square root of the candidate.

Comment: I understand the difference now. But taking a look at the first p number the computer executes, which is 5, wouldn't the loop terminate since 5/3 is less than 3?

Comment: The inner loop, which tests whether `p` is a prime terminates. Then, since `isPrime` wasn't set to false, 5 is written to the `prime` array at place `primeIndex` (2), `primeIndex` is incremented and the outer loop goes into the next round, adding 2 to `p` and thus checking 7. Again the inner loop finishes immediately, `primes[3] = 7`, outer loop with `p = 9`...